# MKMapView GPS location question

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie.. I have a doubt in MapView and CoreLocation. How to make the mapview to display "blue dot and circle animation" as in Locate Me action of Maps app? The solution may be very simple, but I don't have much idea about map in iPhone. Help me, pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
yourMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
```

Put this in your viewforAnnotation Delegate

```
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) 
{ 
    //You can customize the blue dot current location annotation here
    return nil; 
}
```

Comment: thanks man.. I got other problem now. Now its showing the "Red color pin" as the marker. I have set the pin color to red for the other annotations which I am using in the same map view. Do I have to add some more code to distinguish this "current location" marker? or there is any default solution for this? Help me..

Comment: put this code in viewForAnnotation delegate  if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
  return nil;
 }

Comment: Hi.. Add the line in your comment to the answer. I mean the **put this code in viewForAnnotation delegate if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) { return nil; } ** line.